# save_and_show_page does not show page if test ends too quickly

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

[Capybara](http://jnicklas.github.io/capybara/), a web testing library for Ruby, has a method [Capybara::Session.save_and_show_page](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Asave_and_open_page) that brings up the current web page in the browser.  This appears to work asynchronously--the web page is shown some time after the call is made.  That's fine, but if the test ends too quickly after the call to #save_and_show_page, then no web page is shown.

## Problem code

Given this Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "launchy"
gem "poltergeist"
```

Then this code does not display a web page:

```
require "capybara/poltergeist"
session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
session.visit("http://www.google.com")
session.save_and_open_page
```

## Workaround

Adding a brief sleep at the end of the code causes the web page to be displayed, as desired:

```
require "capybara/poltergeist"
session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
session.visit("http://www.google.com")
session.save_and_open_page
sleep 1
# => Opening "/home/wayne/homesmart/franchise-manager-qa/capybara-201610141504469160970532.html" with Google Chrome  (text/html)
# => [10253:10281:1014/150446:ERROR:nss_util.cc(809)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
# => Created new window in existing browser session.
```

**How can I cause Capybara's #save_and_open_page method to always display a page, without having to insert a sleep after calling the method?**

## Versions

- Ruby 2.3.1p112
- [capybara](http://jnicklas.github.io/capybara/) 2.10.1
- [launchy](https://rubygems.org/gems/launchy/versions/2.4.3) 2.4.3
- [poltergeist](https://rubygems.org/gems/poltergeist) 1.11.10
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) 2.1.1
- Google Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)
- Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian

Comment: I can't replicate this on MacOS using the code you provided so it could be a platform specific issue with the launchy gem.  Just want to confirm you don't have an after suite hook that's removing all the saved pages do you?

Comment: @Tom Thank you for looking at this.  I have no after suite hook--the code titled "problem code" is all that is needed to cause it to happen for me.